# How can I disabled other dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to disabled "Province", "City", and "Barangay". When I click the "Region" the "Province" should be enabled. When I choose one option in "Province" the "City" should enabled and so on..

```js
    function dynamicdropdownProvince(listindex)
 {
  switch (listindex) {
  case "metromanila" :
   document.getElementById('provincestatus').options[0]=new Option("Province","");
   document.getElementById("provincestatus").options[1]=new Option("Metro Manila","metromanila");
   break;   
  case "mindanao" :
   document.getElementById("provincestatus").options[0]=new Option("Province","");
   document.getElementById("provincestatus").options[1]=new Option("Agusan Del Norte","agusandelnorte");
   break;
  }
  return true;
 }

 function dynamicdropdownCity(listindex)
 {
  switch (listindex) {
    case "agusandelnorte" :
   document.getElementById("citystatus").options[0]=new Option("City","");
   document.getElementById("citystatus").options[1]=new Option("Buenavista","buenavista");
   break;
    case "metromanila" :
   document.getElementById("citystatus").options[0]=new Option("City","");
   document.getElementById("citystatus").options[1]=new Option("Binondo","binondo");
   break;
  }
  return true;
 }

 function dynamicdropdownBarangay(listindex)
 {
  switch (listindex) {
  case "buenavista" :
    document.getElementById("barangaystatus").options[0]=new Option("Barangay","barangaystatus");
    document.getElementById("barangaystatus").options[1]=new Option("Alubijid","alubijid");
    break;
  case "binondo" :
    document.getElementById("barangaystatus").options[0]=new Option("Barangay","barangaystatus");
    document.getElementById("barangaystatus").options[1]=new Option("Barangay 287","barangay287");
    break;
  }
  return true;
    }
```

```html
<div>
<input class="input-field" name="postal" type="text" placeholder="Postal Code" name="postal" required>  
 <select class="input-field" name="region" id="region" onclick="makeDisable()" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdownProvince(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
  <option disabled selected>Region</option> 
  <option value="metromanila">Metro Manila</option>
  <option value="mindanao">Mindanao</option>
  <option value="northluzon">North Luzon</option>
  <option value="southluzon">South Luzon</option>
  <option value="visayas">Visayas</option> 
 </select>

 <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
  document.write('<select class="input-field" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdownCity(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);" name="provincestatus," id="provincestatus"><option value="">Province</option></select>')
  document.write('<select class="input-field" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdownBarangay(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);" name="citystatus" id="citystatus"><option value="">City</option></select>')
  document.write('<select class="input-field" name="barangaystatus" id="barangaystatus"><option value="" >Barangay</option></select>')
 </script>
 </div>
```

Comment: Have you made any _attempt_ to achieve this?

Comment: I only use the code above. No other than that sir.

Comment: Okay, so how are we supposed to know what you're having trouble with, when you haven't even tried anything?  This isn't really a place to just post your requirements and hope someone does it for you.  If your real question is "how do I disable a dropdown (select element)", a simple Google search should answer that for you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `disabled` property of the element

```js
    document.write('<select class="input-field" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdownCity(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);" name="provincestatus" id="provincestatus" disabled><option value="">Province</option></select>')
    document.write('<select class="input-field" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdownBarangay(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);" name="citystatus" id="citystatus" disabled><option value="">City</option></select>')
    document.write('<select class="input-field" name="barangaystatus" id="barangaystatus" disabled><option value="" >Barangay</option></select>')


function dynamicdropdownProvince(listindex)
{
    switch (listindex)
    {
    case "metromanila" :
        document.getElementById('provincestatus').options[0]=new Option("Province","");
        document.getElementById("provincestatus").options[1]=new Option("Metro Manila","metromanila");
        document.getElementById("provincestatus").disabled=false;
        break;   
    case "mindanao" :
        document.getElementById("provincestatus").options[0]=new Option("Province","");
        document.getElementById("provincestatus").options[1]=new Option("Agusan Del Norte","agusandelnorte");
        document.getElementById("provincestatus").disabled=false;
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
function dynamicdropdownCity(listindex)
{
    switch (listindex)
    {
      case "agusandelnorte" :
        document.getElementById("citystatus").options[0]=new Option("City","");
        document.getElementById("citystatus").options[1]=new Option("Buenavista","buenavista");
        document.getElementById("citystatus").disabled=false;
        break;
      case "metromanila" :
        document.getElementById("citystatus").options[0]=new Option("City","");
        document.getElementById("citystatus").options[1]=new Option("Binondo","binondo");
        document.getElementById("citystatus").disabled=false;
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
function dynamicdropdownBarangay(listindex)
{
    switch (listindex)
    {
    case "buenavista" :
      document.getElementById("barangaystatus").options[0]=new Option("Barangay","barangaystatus");
      document.getElementById("barangaystatus").options[1]=new Option("Alubijid","alubijid");
      document.getElementById("barangaystatus").disabled=false;
      break;
    case "binondo" :
      document.getElementById("barangaystatus").options[0]=new Option("Barangay","barangaystatus");
      document.getElementById("barangaystatus").options[1]=new Option("Barangay 287","barangay287");
      document.getElementById("barangaystatus").disabled=false;
      break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

```html
<input class="input-field" name="postal" type="text" placeholder="Postal Code" name="postal" required>  
<select class="input-field" name="region" id="region" onclick="makeDisable()" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdownProvince(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
    <option disabled selected>Region</option> 
    <option value="metromanila">Metro Manila</option>
    <option value="mindanao">Mindanao</option>
    <option value="northluzon">North Luzon</option>
    <option value="southluzon">South Luzon</option>
    <option value="visayas">Visayas</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: How can I refresh other dropdown when I choose one option in "Region"?

Comment: Refresh means ?? You want to show the dropdown option based on the selected ?